# Sprite will not move within my .txt based map

Tags: java

I am trying to get my Zombie to move around (using keypressed) in the map I made (using scanner and file reader), however it just procreates and then sits there. I still have more code to do as the program isnt finished but I cant do anything else until the Zombie moves. Thanks in advance for any help!

PS. EZ is a multimedia library designed to make it easier for novice programmers to quickly build Java applications that incorporate graphics and sound. It is utilized at UH Hawaii at Manoa.

[zombie sprite sheet](https://www.themanaworld.org/images/b/b2/Monster-zombie.png)

[barbwire](https://img2.annthegran.com/StockDesign/XLarge/Dakota_Collectibles/hr1018.jpg)

[brains](http://www.creativevirtual.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/big-brain-transparent-background3.png)

```
40 26

WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
M                                      M
M                                  B   M
M       B              B               M
M                                      M
M                 M                    M
M   M             M                    M
M   M             WWW                  M
M   WWWW                      B        M
M   M                                  M 
M   M                                  M
M                 B                    M
M      B                               M
M                         WWWWWW       M
M                         M            M
M            B            M            M
M                         M            M
M                         M    B       M
M                         M            M
M     WWWWWWW                          M
M           M                          M
M           M     B                    M
M      B                           B   M
M                                      M
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
```

**Zombie**

```
public class Zombie {

    EZImage zombieSheet;

    int x = 0;                // Position of Sprite
    int y = 0;
    int zombieWidth;        // Width of each sprite
    int zombieHeight;        // Height of each sprite
    int direction = 0;        // Direction character is walking in
    int walkSequence = 0;    // Walk sequence counter
    int cycleSteps;            // Number of steps before cycling to next animation step
    int counter = 0;        // Cycle counter

    Zombie(String imgFile, int startX, int startY, int width, int height, int steps) {
        x = startX;                    // position of the sprite character on the screen
        y = startY;
        zombieWidth = width;        // Width of the sprite character
        zombieHeight = height;        // Height of the sprite character
        cycleSteps = steps;            // How many pixel movement steps to move before changing the sprite graphic
        zombieSheet = EZ.addImage(imgFile, x, y);
        setImagePosition();
    }

    private void setImagePosition() {

        // Move the entire sprite sheet
        zombieSheet.translateTo(x, y);

        // Show only a portion of the sprite sheet.
        // Portion is determined by setFocus which takes 4 parameters:
        // The 1st two numbers is the top left hand corner of the focus region.
        // The 2nd two numbers is the bottom right hand corner of the focus region.
        zombieSheet.setFocus(walkSequence * zombieWidth, direction, walkSequence * zombieWidth + zombieWidth, direction + zombieHeight);
    }

    public void moveDown(int stepSize) {
        y = y + stepSize;

        direction = 0;

        if ((counter % cycleSteps) == 0) {
            walkSequence++;
            if (walkSequence > 3)
                walkSequence = 0;
        }
        counter++;
        setImagePosition();
    }

    public void moveLeft(int stepSize) {
        x = x - stepSize;
        direction = zombieHeight;

        if ((counter % cycleSteps) == 0) {
            walkSequence--;
            if (walkSequence < 0)
                walkSequence = 3;
        }
        counter++;
        setImagePosition();
    }

    public void moveRight(int stepSize) {
        x = x + stepSize;
        direction = zombieHeight * 2;

        if ((counter % cycleSteps) == 0) {
            walkSequence++;
            if (walkSequence > 3)
                walkSequence = 0;
        }
        counter++;

        setImagePosition();
    }

    public void moveUp(int stepSize) {
        y = y - stepSize;
        direction = zombieHeight * 3;

        if ((counter % cycleSteps) == 0) {
            walkSequence--;
            if (walkSequence < 0)
                walkSequence = 3;
        }
        setImagePosition();

        counter++;
    }

    // Keyboard controls for moving the character.
    public void go() {
        if (EZInteraction.isKeyDown('w')) {
            moveUp(2);
        } else if (EZInteraction.isKeyDown('a')) {
            moveLeft(2);
        } else if (EZInteraction.isKeyDown('s')) {
            moveDown(2);
        } else if (EZInteraction.isKeyDown('d')) {
            moveRight(2);
        }
    }
}
```

**ZombieMain**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ZombieMain {

    static EZImage[] walls = new EZImage[500];
    static EZImage[] sideWalls = new EZImage[500];
    static EZImage[] brains = new EZImage[50];
    static int wallsCount = 0;
    static int sideWallsCount = 0;
    static int brainsCount = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {

        //initialize scanner
        Scanner fScanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("boundaries.txt"));

        int w = fScanner.nextInt();
        int h = fScanner.nextInt();
        String inputText = fScanner.nextLine();

        //create backdrop
        EZ.initialize(w * 33, h * 32);
        EZ.setBackgroundColor(new Color(0, 0, 0));
        Zombie me = new Zombie("zombieSheet.png", 650, 450, 48, 58, 10);

        //set reading parameters and establish results of case readings
        for (int row = 0; row < 41; row++) {

            inputText = fScanner.nextLine();

            for (int column = 0; column < inputText.length(); column++) {

                char ch = inputText.charAt(column);

                switch (ch) {
                    case 'W':
                        walls[wallsCount] = EZ.addImage("barbwire.jpg", column * 32, row * 32);
                        wallsCount++;
                        break;
                    case 'M':
                        sideWalls[wallsCount] = EZ.addImage("barb.jpg", column * 32, row * 32);
                        wallsCount++;
                        break;
                    case 'B':
                        brains[brainsCount] = EZ.addImage("brains.png", column * 32, row * 32);
                        brainsCount++;
                        break;
                    default:
                        // Do nothing
                        break;
                }

                //printed count of walls, side walls, and brains
                System.out.println("W = " + wallsCount);
                System.out.println("M = " + sideWallsCount);
                System.out.println("B = " + brainsCount);
            }
        }
        fScanner.close();

        while (true) {
            me.go();
            EZ.refreshScreen();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code looks reasonable. It's hard to say anything more without looking at the sources of the EZ library and how it handles character input.

Comment: http://www2.hawaii.edu/~dylank/ics111/   is the link to the webpage where it is sourced.

Comment: Could you share the images / boundaries.txt file?

Comment: @PiotrWilkin I linked the sprite sheet and edited in the boundaries.txt

Comment: You might want to link the other images as well.

Comment: @PiotrWilkin also added barb wire and brains picture, although come to think of it i believe i resized them

Answer (score 0):

Okay, got it.

You use a `for` loop for iterating the text file with the map. Your `for` loop assumes that your map file has exactly 41 lines. It doesn't, therefore the scanner throws an exception when it reaches outside the loop.

Generally, assuming a fixed size is a bad solution when reading files. What you should do is use some sort of method (that is usually provided with such readers) that checks whether you have not reached the end, and use a `while` loop. Since you need a row number anyways, you need to keep a separate counter for it and increment it in every `while` loop pass.

In the case of scanner, the method you're looking for is `fScanner.hasNext()`, so your code would look like this:

```
    int row = 0;
    //set reading parameters and establish results of case readings
    while (fScanner.hasNext()) {
         ...
         row++;
    }
```

Comment: Also, as a general rule, pay attention to the console and see if any errors are thrown. If your application crashes, it won't really do anything else. In the case of a graphical application, it might not clean up all of its threads, so the main code might crash, but the graphical engine might keep on running. Also, it's really worthwhile to learn to use a debugger.

Comment: well i can move my sprite now, but i think i might have input my while loop and my row++ in the wrong spot because now my map isnt displayed correctly

Comment: Use `while` in place of the external `for` loop and remember that the `row++` has to be at the end of the **external** loop (i.e. after the internal `for` loop that loops over the columns).

Comment: you are awesome! thanks for helping out this brand new java student!